# Require attribution with AGPL

Tags: gpl, license-recommendation, agpl-3.0, attribution, agpl

I've read

- [Is ONLYOFFICE restricting our freedom with their FAQ? (AGPL v3)](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/is-onlyoffice-restricting-our-freedom-with-their-faq-agpl-v3/9482#9482)
- and [What are the attribution requirements of the AGPL license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/what-are-the-attribution-requirements-of-the-agpl-license?rq=1)

but can't come to a definitive answer - how can I require attribution **visible to the end user** for the derived works?

If competitors are going to monetize my software, I want to (at least) get attribution.

What I understood from the referenced questions/answers is that s7(b) of the AGPLv3:

> b) **Requiring preservation of** specified reasonable legal notices or
> **author attributions in that material or in the Appropriate Legal
> Notices displayed by works containing it**; or

allows me do add additional terms to require attribution, but how can I require it to be visible for the end user of the web application (instead of shown in the source code or some other barely visible place) for all the derived works?

**Ideally with the link and logo.**

Something like Algolia does with "**Search by Algolia**"
[image: Search by Algolia]

If this is not possible, what can I do with the AGPLv3 to be close to that, or which Open Source license covers this use case, I'm sure it's a common scenario?

Thank you!